# Runtime methods objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have problem with my "runtime class".

I have class that class is subclass of another class.

I have this part of code:

```
Method * mlist = class_copyMethodList([mainClass class], &method_count);
```

But this code return only methods from child class.
I need methods from parent class.

Is any solution for my problem?

Comment: What are the class names?  What type is `mainClass`?  How is that variable initialized?

Comment: mainClass is ViewController that extends ParentViewController.

I try use class_getSuperclass(class) in recursive mode, but it is included with SDK ViewController, UIResponder and more class. I need only my project classes.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just call `class_copyMethodList()` with the classes whose methods you are interested in.  `class_copyMethodList([Class class]...)`.